# Why I do not see realtime output in the output file?

Tags: python, file, output

I thought writing a file gives real-time output, since it is so when I use C/C++ to write files. But when I run python program it seems the output file is always 0 byte until the whole program finished running. Even for the `nohup python xxx.py &`, the `print` stuff in the file `nohup.out` isn't realtime, and can only be seen after execution.
I'm now running really big program and want to see the progress in the file, how can I achieve it?

Comment: you may have to flash it f.flush()

Comment: Flush the output buffer. It will write in chunks for performance reasons.

Comment: @JohnFoley By the way, if I do f.flush() very frequently does it harm the efficiency very much?

Comment: not an expert on it but i think you can also run python -u file.py and it will do the flashing. dont know any low level details. it maybe better than doing it in a loop.

Comment: @FooBarUser I looked into `-u` and it says it forces the flush of stdout stderr, what about the file? It also does that?

Comment: hm i was not sure about the -u, file.flush() should work

Comment: "*since it is so when I use C/C++ to write files*" - Nope. Writing to a file through `<stdio.h>` routines in C or C++ has precisely the same issue -- buffering -- and precisely the same solution -- `fflush()`.

Comment: @FooBarUser Seems `-u` does not flush the file, only stdout

Comment: @Robᵩ Oh, thanks for the clarification. It seems I don't know what I'm talking about..

Comment: @LoganYang - Sorry, I didn't mean to be short with you. Just trying to help, sometimes clumsily.

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks really, your clarification is important to me! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two points at which your file can buffer - Python's internal buffers and the buffers on the operating system. This is a performance boost that avoids system calls and disk writes while the buffer is filling up.

Calling `file.flush()` will push the internal buffer to the operating system. You can additionally call `fsync` to request the operating system to save to disk.

Usually you can leave the operating system to do what it knows best, so calling `flush` is usually enough for most applications. The same is partially true for Python's internal buffer - it knows best in terms of performance, but you may require more frequent writes and be willing to pay the additional cost. The only way to know the exact cost is to measure it both ways.